# Laravel disable choosing end date before choosing start date

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-ui-datepicker

I tried to disable end period date to prevent user from choosing end date before they choose start date first, here is my code :

```
// Datepicker
        
    $('.dtpicker').datepicker({
            startDate: new Date(),
            format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
            todayBtn: "linked",
            autoclose: true,
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#periode_end").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $("#periode_start").datepicker({
        todayBtn:  "linked",
        format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
            var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());

        $("periode_end").removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#periode_end').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
        });

        $("#periode_end").datepicker({
            format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
            autoclose: true,
        })
        .on('changeDate', function (selected) {
            var maxDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
            $('#periode_start').datepicker('setEndDate', maxDate);
        });

    });
```

but it disable end date completely, even if user already input the start date. Am I missing something or anyone has an solution?, thanks.

Comment: I removed the Laravel tag as this has nothing to do with Laravel; I thought it is jQuery UI Datepicker but probably it is not - I don't think `autoclose` or `todayBtn` are properties for that datepicker? You might want to identify which one you are using.

Comment: appologize for the confusing tag, i really dont know which tag to choose and since i was using laravel framework and then that become the tag i choose and also because im still new with jquery.

Comment: What datepicker are you using? I added a tag for jQuery UI datepicker but I don't think that is right.  Edit your question, tag/describe which datepicker you are using.

Comment: to be completely honest i dont even know which one, but as far as i know it was jQuery UI since im also still new using laravel, jQuery, and datatables as well, and again apologize for the confusing tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try read the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), you can set the minDate with:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) );
```

So at your condition you can try :

```
$('.dtpicker').datepicker({
    startDate: new Date(),
    format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    autoclose: true,
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#periode_end").prop("disabled", true)
    .datepicker({
        format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var maxDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('#periode_start').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate);
    });

    $("#periode_start").datepicker({
        todayBtn:  "linked",
        format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        //here you set disabled to false, and set min date for periode_end
        $("#periode_end").prop("disabled", false)
        .datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for this, the code is disable the periode_end to be choosen and this make user must choose the periode_start first, but sadly the periode_end can still choose a date fewer than the periode_start, but this is really helpfull and i would like to figure out the rest myself, thanks again!.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

// Datepicker

```
$('.dtpicker').datepicker({
        startDate: new Date(),
        format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        autoclose: true,
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#periode_end").attr('disabled', true);

$("#periode_start").datepicker({
    todayBtn:  "linked",
    format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());

    
  **// add this**
    if(!new Date($(this).val())){
           $("#periode_end").attr('disabled', true);
    }else{
           $("#periode_end").attr('disabled', false);
    }

    //

    $('#periode_end').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    });

    $("#periode_end").datepicker({
        format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
    })
    .on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var maxDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('#periode_start').datepicker('setEndDate', maxDate);
    });

});
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help, but sadly it doesnt work and it completely disable my datatables.